# How to retrieve form field value using PHP Post

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form with field names like field11, field12, field13 in the first row and field21, field22, field23 in the second row and so on. I have this dynamic naming structure, because the user sets the number of rows and columns. I use two nested PHP for loops to build this table. Everything works fine until I submit the form and wish to retrieve the values on the next page. To retrieve field21, I need to use $_POST["field21"]. But I am using this inside a double for loop where $i=2 and $j=1. In essence, I need to use something like $_POST["field . $i . $j"]. I am not able to get the correct syntax.

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= $sailings; $j++) {
for ($i = 1; $i < $ratecols; $i++) {

echo "<td><input name='field" . $j . $i . "' id='field" . $j . $i . "' type='text'></td>";

}
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? reading the values after form submission not knowing how many rows and columns exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead - use `[]` notation for `name` attribute of your `input`s:

```
<input name="field[1][1]" type='text' />
<input name="field[1][2]" type='text' />
<input name="field[1][3]" type='text' />
<input name="field[2][1]" type='text' />
<input name="field[2][2]" type='text' />
<input name="field[2][3]" type='text' />
```

On server iterate over `$_POST['field']`:

```
foreach ($_POST['field'] as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo $value; 
        // other code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the field values the way you are outputting them you can do it like this:

```
for ($j = 1; isset($_POST['field' . $j . 1]); $j++) {
    for ($i = 1; isset($_POST['field' . $j . $i]); $i++) {
        echo $_POST['field' . $j . $i];
    }
}
```

Although I suggest you use the approach posted by u_mulder since it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a key value foreach loop:

```
<?php

$_POST = [
  'var1' => 'www',
  'var2' => 'xxx',
  'var3' => 'yyy',
  'var4' => 'zzz',  
];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Form field ' . $key . ' = ' . $value . "\n";
}
```

Which will output:

```
Form field var1 = www 
Form field var2 = xxx 
Form field var3 = yyy 
Form field var4 = zzz
```

Which you can see here https://3v4l.org/FKlY8